# Custom TextView not visible in 5.0 and higher devices

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Following is my custom TextView Class:

```
public class MontTextView extends  android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{  
public MontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
} 
public MontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
} 
public MontTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
} 
public void init() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf");
    setTypeface(tf ,1); 
    }
}
```

And in XML I use it like this:

```
<com.minimalist.gorakh.customviews.MontTextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_25ssp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/betaView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/betaView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/betaView" />
```

This is working in pre-lollipop(v-19) like this:
[image: pre-lollipop]

And on a marshmallow emulator:
[image]

I copied the custom TextView code from a previous project, but couldn't get what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```java
import android.widget.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.graphics.*;

public class MontTextView extends TextView{  


    public MontTextView (Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MontTextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MontTextView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),  "fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf"));
    }

}
```